# List all Airtable tables via API request

Tags: airtable

Given that user provided his API key, is there a way to retrieve a list of tables in user's AirTable account?

I do know there is a URL for API queries, with base and table encoded there. Also API docs include only info on how to work with a particular table.

My use case is to allow user to choose a table they want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This would be part of the metadata API which does not exist.

See this [community](https://community.airtable.com/t/python-script-to-retrieve-schema-from-an-airtable-base/8985) post for some non-api workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Airtable now offers a Metadata Api, however access is limited and must be individually requested, at this time.

> As part of our ongoing effort to make Airtable more and more extensible, we’re beginning to expand access to the Metadata API 360.
>
> The metadata API gives you read-only access to a list of a user’s bases, as well as the specific schema of each base - things like what tables exist, what fields exist on those tables, etc.
> https://community.airtable.com/t/accessing-the-metadata-api/37080

[Metadata Api Documentation](https://airtable.com/api/meta)

[Enterprise API](https://airtable.com/api/enterprise) also offers endpoints capable of fetching Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Get all bases by calling `https://api.airtable.com/v0/meta/bases`
2. Get all tables by calling (for each base) `https://api.airtable.com/v0/meta/bases/${baseId}/tables`